# Beamer frame with two columns and two images on the same column

Tags: beamer, multicolumn

I need to divide a frame into two columns and the left column I need to put two or three images, one above the other and in the right column text.
How can I do that?

Comment: If they are not all the same size, you can align them by putting them into a tabular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `columns` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
text
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```